# Display jpg from sdcard android

Tags: java, android

I cant get this to work anymore

Here is my code:

```
ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/pic.jpg";              

    jpgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //jpgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    jpgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);


  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
  options.inSampleSize = 2;
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options);
  jpgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your log?

Comment: I think im having problem with the sdcard, filewont donwload to it (checked using devtools>term emulator) and also the image will never load into the image view. Is it possible to save to internel memory instead of this sdcard emulate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use bitmapdrawable, e.g.

```
ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/pic.jpg";
BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myJpgPath);
jpgView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: I think Im having a problem with the sdcard. For example, this app is meant to download a file via ftp and then display it in a imageview. Here is the full class, if you could help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I try to load image from sdcard the imageview just stays blank. If I try to download using the ftp class "client", the file no longer saves to sdcard. Is it possible to sae the fetched ftp file into internel memory instead of the sdcard? Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, the imageview works if i load a png using android:scr = "@drawable/icon" for example

Answer (score 2):

The image won't be shown if you open the emulator directly from the eclipse, by clicking run. You'll be able to access the SD card if you start the emulator using the command line, then click your app on the emulator.